# What Is The Callback Method When A Daemon Application Exists

Tags: c#

I need to be able to create a little daemon application that will keep running until the machine is restarted or the process is forcefully killed.

Is there a callback I can implement to get called when the application is exiting (either by force or at system shutdown)

I am not creating a Windows form but a daemon application - I have serached google with no luck

Answer (score 3):

Why not just make a [Windows Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx)?  This, by default, will startup when the system boots, and remain running until shutdown.

Comment: Interesting idea - The only thing that comes to mind here is if someone logs you out will the service die?  I need to get notified of restarts and log outs of a particulr user name :(

Comment: No.  Services run separate from user logins.  They're the only real way to make this work...

Comment: Thanks Reed - So I dont see how this solution would work in that case.  How will I know if a user has logged out which is an event I want to capture?

Comment: You need to use WMI to track the Win32_LogonSession events from your service.  This will provide you the means to track user login/logout from your service.